# Magento: Get custom attribute text on Admin Grid of Category > Product Tab Grid

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I'm using the following code to pull a custom attribute into the Admin Catalog> Product Tab Grid.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('pos_product_type')
```

+

```
 $this->addColumn('pos_product_type', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('OsiPos Category'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'width'     => '80',
        'index'     => 'pos_product_type'
    ));
```

This shows the attribute id, eg 92, 97, 95. This isn't very user friendly so I'm wondering how I could go about getting the actual name / label of the attribute.

On the frontend I would use:

```
 $_product->getAttributeText('pos_product_type')
```

to display the label but I can't convert the it on the back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were getting close with the suggestions but the final solution came from the following:

```
// Add Pos Product Type

    $pos_items = 
    Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')->getCollection()->setStoreFilter()->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code');
            foreach ($pos_items as $pos_item) :
                if ($pos_item->getAttributeCode() == 'pos_product_type')
                    $pos_options[$pos_item->getOptionId()] = $pos_item->getValue();
            endforeach;

            $this->addColumn('pos_product_type',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Pos Product Type'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'index' => 'pos_product_type',
                    'options' => $pos_options
            ));
```

Comment: @mahmoudismail - this was 6 years ago and relevant for Magento 1.5. This code base is long gone so I cannot get the full code. Try searching for something more recent, and probably for Magento 2+ given that 1.x is being depreciated in less than a year.

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answers at Magento code, check for example **visibility**:

```
$this->addColumn('visibility',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
        'width' => '70px',
        'index' => 'visibility',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
));
```

---

Also you can check code for attribute set, which communicate with db.

```
$sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
    ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
    ->load()
    ->toOptionHash();

$this->addColumn('set_name',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
        'width' => '100px',
        'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => $sets,
));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this throws: Warning: include(Mage/Catalog/Model/Pos/Product/Type.php): failed to open stream:

Comment: check this method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::getOptionArray`.

Comment: Did you try the second part?

Comment: Yes, no luck. It returned blank column fields. But the filter had the main attribute group. i.e. Default

Answer (score 1):

This is easy achievable with: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl

*EDIT*

What you want is to add the options to your column:

```
$this->addColumn('pos_product_type', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('OsiPos Category'),
    'sortable'  => true,
    'width'     => '80',
    'index'     => 'pos_product_type',
    'options' => $this->_getProductAttributeOptions('pos_product_type')
));
```

I should copy the helper function with:

```
protected function _getProductAttributeOptions($attributeName) {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$attributeName);
    /* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */       
    $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    $options = array();
    // options in key => value Format bringen
    foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
        $options[number_format($option['value'], 4, '.', '')] = $option['label'];
    }       
    return $options;       
}
```

Thanks to the webguys: http://www.webguys.de/magento/turchen-23-pimp-my-produktgrid/

But you don't understand german, do you?

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks very interesting! However this is as much me trying to learn more about the workings of Magento as it as to finding a solution. So I would like to find a non module solution. +1 for the reference!

Comment: then have a look into the extension ;-) It makes more or less the same you have to do. it hooks into `core_collection_abstract_load_before` to add the attribute to the collection and then into `adminhtml_block_html_before` to add the column to the grid.

Comment: forget what I said. too complex and I didn't read your whole answer. What you need is: `'options' => $this->_getProductAttributeOptions('pos_product_type')` in your `addColumn()`

Comment: :( - Invalid method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product::_getProductAttributeOptions(Array
(
    [0] => pos_product_type
)
)

Comment: No, I didn't get a notice when you edited it only from your comment. I tried your public function but I ended up with an error. `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given  in...` I'm afraid I don't speak German so I can't read through the link you sent for more information. I was pasting the protected function in various places in the product.php file, but it all returned the same error.

Comment: have a look into $option['value'], what is it? I think you are working with strings instead of ints for values. If $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() is already in the form array(key => value) you can return it. If not rebuild it. But this should be the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to filter the attribute code using MySQL instead of PHP performance sake. The list of attributes and options can get pretty big over time, no need to loop through them all.

Below a modified example:

```
$pos_items = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setStoreFilter()
            ->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code')
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'pos_product_type');

   foreach ($pos_items as $pos_item) :
                $pos_options[$pos_item->getOptionId()] = $pos_item->getValue();
        endforeach;

$this->addColumn('pos_product_type',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Pos Product Type'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'index' => 'pos_product_type',
                'options' => $pos_options
        ));
```